# How to create a 2d arrayList,?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  a[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

I'm getting errors like array required but arrayList found!!
how to assign an object at some specified index of an arraylist.
Is there any other simple alternative to create a Two dimensional arraylist ?

Comment: Yep, maybe! I want to create an arrayList to store other arraylist...how's it possible?

Comment: Good site with an example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-of-arraylist-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a 2d `ArrayList`, type of `a` and how you add elements to `a` should be as follows,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<>();
  a.add(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a ArrayList to store Integers. If you want to create a ArrayList to store ArrayList you can do like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integers>> arr = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<arr.size;i++){
   arr.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```